# how to store date and timezone in Indian Standard Time(IST) format in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, moment-timezone

I have installed moment-timezone node-module and getting the date correctly but when I try to save it to database it is converting back into some another time-zone.

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const dateIndia = moment.tz(Date.now(), "Asia/Kolkata");
console.log(dateIndia);
```

Here console is printing the correct IST time:

```
Moment<2022-06-04T15:08:08+05:30>
```

Then I am storing it into the database from schema:

```
bookingDate: {
    type: Date, 
    default: dateIndia,
    required: true,
  },
```

But it is saving date into UTC timezone like this:

```
2022-06-04T09:18:38.540+00:00
```

Comment: MongoDB stores Date/Time as UTC time - **always and only**. If you need to preserve the input time zone then you need to store it in a separate field.

Answer (score 0):

That is not about your NodeJS. That is your database time-zone configuration.
You can solve that with one of the 2 below:

1 - Change your database time-zone configurations
2 - When you get from the database just use the same function you used to create the date and convert it back to the timezone you want:

```
let dateUTC = (moment.tz(databaseDate, "UTC");
let dateIndia = dateUTC.tz("Asia/Kolkata").format()
```

Comment: How to change time-zone configuration in database?

Comment: If you are using mysql : `SET GLOBAL time_zone = Asia/Kolkata;` If you are using mongodb then you have to use UTC.